# Triggering nested javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm relatively new to javascript and I've been banging my head against an issue all day - I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a PHP script that does a slideshow. I have NEXT and PREVIOUS buttons which contain dynamic links to another javascript function. I'm hoping to find a way of triggering them with the arrow keys on the keyboard.

So far, I've found a way of making the arrow keys launch particular URLs but I'm struggling a bit now. The target URLs change as a result of hiding and showing DIVs on the page. So I think I need to do one of the following:

Trigger this code with URLS constructed within PHP variables later in the main body of the page - without refreshing the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).keydown(function(e){

 //e.which is set by jQuery for those browsers that do not normally support e.keyCode.
 var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

if (keyCode == 37)
 {
 window.location = 'http://www.domain.com/previous-image.jpg';
 return false;
 }

 if (keyCode == 39)
 {
 window.location = 'http://www.domain.com/next-image.jpg';
 return false;
 }

});

</script>
```

...or I need to find a way of triggering a link within a DIV of a particular name - but only if the DIV is not hidden.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Edit: 10/10/12

Thanks for everyone's help so far. I now understand a bit more and I can perhaps be clearer with what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a page which has 5 DIVs - 4 of which are hidden. Each is identical except for the image displayed in it and I use the following code to hide or show the various DIVs: http://jsfiddle.net/edzpgt/ZhjRc/12/

I need to use arrow keys to navigate the pages so I'll add some Jquery for this as we've already discussed: http://jsfiddle.net/edzpgt/b2bWz/3/

I think I have two issues:
1. I'm not sure I have the syntax correct in order to make sure I'm only using the arrow key links from the visible DIV.
2. I don't think I'm setting or using the next/previous page number variable correctly in order to get the right desintation URL passed to the Jquery.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

1) You don't need to handle `e.keyCode || e.which`. jQuery does that for you. Just use `e.which`

2) It's better to make two functions outside of handler so you can call them from elsewhere:

```
function previousLocation() {
    window.location = 'http://www.domain.com/previous-image.jpg';
}

function nextLocation() {
    window.location = 'http://www.domain.com/next-image.jpg';
}

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.which;

    if (keyCode == 37) {
        previousLocation();
        return false;
    }

    if (keyCode == 39) {
        nextLocation();
        return false;
    }

});
```

3) But if you really need to trigger - here's example:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.which;

    function previousLocation() {
        window.location = 'http://www.domain.com/previous-image.jpg';
    }

    function nextLocation() {
        window.location = 'http://www.domain.com/next-image.jpg';
    }

    $(document).bind('goprev', previousLocation);
    $(document).bind('gonext', nextLocation);

    if (keyCode == 37) {
        previousLocation(); // no problems here
        return false;
    }

    if (keyCode == 39) {
        nextLocation(); // no problems here
        return false;
    }

});

// external call example
$(document).trigger('goprev');
$(document).trigger('gonext');
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections - Does this allow me to use a PHP variable as the destination URL though?

Comment: Of course you can use that. Just make two global JS variables using  PHP and update functions like `window.location = variable1;`

Comment: Is this as simple as this or am I missing something?:

`<?$variable="http://www.domain.com";?>`

Comment: Maybe something like this: <script>var link1 = '<?php echo $phpvar ?>';</script>

Comment: Thanks for this but I can't seem to get it to work. I've edited my original post which might make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a nice [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function that may work for you.

```
if (keyCode == 37)
 {
 $("#next").trigger("click");
 return false;
 }

 if (keyCode == 39)
 {
 $("#prev").trigger("click");
 return false;
 }
```

You would need to substitute `#next` and `#previous` with the valid selectors for the next and previous links. Without the HTML, I used those as place holders.

**[EXAMPLE:](http://jsfiddle.net/KUTmp/)**

**HTML**

```
​<a href="#" rel="next">next</a>
<a href="#" rel="prev">prev</a>​
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
      //e.which is set by jQuery for those browsers that do not normally support e.keyCode.
      var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

      if (keyCode == 37)
      {
       $("a[rel='prev']").trigger("click");
       return false;
      }
     else if (keyCode == 39)
     {
       $("a[rel='next']").trigger("click");
       return false;
     }
   });
   $("a[rel='next']").click(function(){
      alert("next");
   });

   $("a[rel='prev']").click(function(){
      alert("prev");
   });
```

Comment: Looks good, but how do I apply the click to the hyperlink?
I mean, what do the #next and #previous tags refer to in your example?

Comment: Thanks Chase - that's clearer and I think I understand. Please see my comment above in reply to Diode though as it applies here, too.

Comment: If it's a case where they are being hidden and show, you could use the selector `:visible`; so something like `$(a[rel='next']:visible).click()`. http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ If you can show me the html structure then I can give you a better example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Chase - I've tried to implement this code today but it didn't seem to work. So, I've created an empty page with just these elements and it's still not working. Nothing happens when the arrow keys are pressed. I'm sure this is something really obvious but i can't spot it!
I was going to copy and paste my simple page code here but it seems I don't have enough characters available in this reply box. I'm a bit puzzled!

Comment: You can edit the original post with the code you would like for me to take a look at, or put it on www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: The thing about jQuery is that event listeners need to be defined withing a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })/`. This was part of the issue. The other is that your `<a>` tags need to have `href` values of `#` so that they don't try to go to a new page. I've updated your example: http://jsfiddle.net/k4Gav/1/

Comment: Thanks. I've got that working in a simplistic form now. I've also tried to apply it to what I was wanting to do before but it's not doing what I want yet. I'm trying to set a variable within the body of the page that I can pass to the jquery script so that it knows what page to load. I've updated the script here:  http://jsfiddle.net/edzpgt/k4Gav/2/

Answer (score 0):

There will be two `a` tags. one for next and other for previous. So first you have to find those. Suppose they are with ids `nextSlide` and `prevSlide` ,

```
<a id="prevSlide" href="http://www.domain.com/previous-image.jpg">Previous</a>
<a id="nextSlide" href="http://www.domain.com/next-image.jpg">Next</a>
```

you have rewrite your code as given below

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){

 //e.which is set by jQuery for those browsers that do not normally support e.keyCode.
 var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

if (keyCode == 37)
 {
 window.location  = $("#prevSlide").attr("href");
 return false;
 }

 if (keyCode == 39)
 {
 window.location  = $("#nextSlide").attr("href");
 return false;
 }

});
```

Comment: Thanks - the issue I have is that there are technically up to 10 'next' tags and 10 'prev' tags since I can have up to 10 images. All coding is present on the page but there's only one visible DIV at a time. Trouble is, I think that the Java is seeing the first one even though it's hidden. I'm trying to work out how best to get around this issue.